# I am implementing bomberman in python and i want to move it continuously.But as i am printing board continuously it is flickering.How to reduce it?

Tags: python, terminal

Actually i am implemeting bomberman game in python and i want to move bomberman continuously left right up down on key presses.

I want to reduce flickering on terminal screen on subsequent display of 2D array. As i keep pressing key for movement in 2D array lower part of 2d array blinks and that is what i want to reduce.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
def printboard(): 
    for x in range(wall1.rows): 
        for y in range(wall1.columns): 
            print(arr[x][y],end='') 
            print('\n',end='') 
        print('\n',end='')
```

class _Getch:
    """Gets a single character from standard input.  Does not echo to the screen."""
    def **init**(self):
        try:
            self.impl = _GetchWindows()
        except ImportError:
            self.impl = _GetchUnix()

```
def __call__(self): return self.impl()
```

class _GetchUnix:
    def **init**(self):
        import tty, sys

```
def __call__(self):
    import sys, tty, termios
    fd = sys.stdin.fileno()
    old_settings = termios.tcgetattr(fd)
    try:
        tty.setraw(sys.stdin.fileno())
        ch = sys.stdin.read(1)
    finally:
        termios.tcsetattr(fd, termios.TCSADRAIN, old_settings)
    return ch
```

class _GetchWindows:
    def **init**(self):
        import msvcrt

```
def __call__(self):
    import msvcrt
    return msvcrt.getch()
```

getch = _Getch()

Comment: Can you provide some code so we know what you're talking about?

Comment: I am just printing 2d array of '#' continuously on key press. As i press a letter it will be printed again on screen so i want to know how to stop/reduce this fliclering. I used getch function for printing on key press and it doesn,t require to press enter after key press.

Comment: Again... can you provide some code?

Comment: Please show us what you have done, the code that's been used as users will find that easer to help u rather than guessing.

http://m.wikihow.com/Ask-a-Question-on-Stack-Overflow

Comment: def printboard():
    for x in range(wall1.rows):
        for y in range(wall1.columns):
            print(arr[x][y],end='')
        print('\n',end='')
    print('\n',end='')while True:
    if bman.is_enemy_nearby():
        lives-=1;
    printboard()    
    inp=getch()

Comment: Please update the question with a full compile-able working piece of code

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood your question correctly then this flickering is due to the fact that the execution time is very fast, so a delay should solve the issue. Try these lines of code:

```
import time

{your code here}
time.sleep(0.5)   # delays for 0.51 seconds. You can Also Use Float Value.
```

Comment: But i dont want delay if key is pressed i want its action immediately. Actually it is a game bomberman where i am moving him left right.

Comment: you would have to add a delay, what you can do is play with this delay such that it is not visible to the user.

Comment: can you elaborate what does play with this delay mean?

Comment: change the delay try to decrease it so you may find a perfect balance.